# Search - autocomplete in drop down list

Tags: excel

I have two sheets in Excel:

**Sheet A**:  Drop down list with source from Sheet B
 **Sheet B**:  One column with names:

```
 NAMES
 James Gordon
 Andrea Michel
 Third Name
```

The list is very long, but unfortunately when I click on the drop down list I can't search in the list.

I need to search in the drop down list, or jump to the character which is pressed.

Any suggestion how to start?

Comment: What about a filter?

Comment: this has always been a limitation of drop-down list based on validation.... If you really want to do this, you could generate a userform with the list and use the KeyUp Events of a textbox to search the list (qualification - I did this in Access, but not in an Excel userform)

Comment: Yes unfortunately this is not possible without VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I used an embedded combo box in a worksheet to achieve this.  I created a named range with the values that I wanted to include in the combo box, then using the properties window input the named_range into the "ListFillRange" property box.  This will allow the drop down box to reference this list, however I never fully figured out how to make the named range dynamically update.

To allow the list to search for included values, you need to set the "MatchEntry" property to 1 - fmMatchEntryComplete.  This should achieve your desired goal.